# Upcoming "clickjacking" protection

Tags: visualforce, clickjacking, api-26

There is a new alert on the Partnerforce portal that is letting partners know of the upcoming "clickjack protection" for non-setup pages in Winter '13. It seems to be stating that if a customer turns this on, ALL framed/iframed pages (Visualforce or otherwise) will stop working.

Does anybody have any more information on this? If I'm reading it correctly, it's going to be an unusable feature for any customer who either has installed a package that uses frames or has done their own custom implementation using frames or iframes. I've personally seen dozens of customers who do this.

If this is the case, I hope SFDC at least has it turned off by default and boldly warns anyone who turns it on that it is likely to break pages if they use frames anywhere.

Does anybody know anything? It sounds like a feature which could potentially break a LOT of managed package features but is seemingly not getting much press. I posted this question in the official Visualforce forum but got no response.

Comment: all custom components embedded into the standard layout are iFrames to date (as I remember) its a major reversal to change that functionality. Personally though, if it turns out to be true and they are instead embedding the code directly into a single page, that would be a big boon. being sandboxed in an iframe is a major pain.

Comment: @ebt my understanding is that iframes will continue to be used as they are today, but cross domain iframes will refuse to render. Salesforce uses a special integration servlet to embed VF pages on layouts today so they won't be affected.

Comment: I just posted a question/scenario that demonstrates a VisualForce component failing in a VisualForce page with this protection enabled. I posted it as a new question (whether it's a bug or expected) as it didn't seem appropriate as an answer to this one.

Comment: Update: kibitzer's post seems to confirm my worst fears. More info here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/winter-13-clickjacking-protection-is-the-following-expected-or-a-bug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's more on this in the [Winter '13 release notes](https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_winter13_release_notes.pdf).

Interpreting the release notes, it looks like you have to go in and enable the settings.  The release notes do inform the user that some pages may display as blank.

> **Clickjacking Protection Available**
>
> You can enable protection against clickjack attacks (also known as user interface redress attacks) for non-setup pages and your custom Visualforce pages. Setup pages already include protection against clickjack attacks. Click **Your Name > Setup > Security Controls > Session Settings** to select:
>    `Enable clickjack protection for non-setup Salesforce pages
>   Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with standard headers
>   Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with headers disabled`
>
> It’s possible that pages will either display as a blank page or
>   without the frame if either of these settings is enabled and either of
>   the following conditions exists:
>
> - Your organization displays Salesforce.com user interface pages within
>     a frame or iframe.
> - You use custom Visualforce pages within a frame or iframe.
>
> The behavior varies depending on your browser and its version. To
>   ensure that these pages will continue to work correctly in your
>   organization, discontinue displaying these pages within a frame or
>   iframe.

Answer (score 5):

I do know that it can optionally be disabled on a per-org basis under Session Settings.

I did just get unofficial word that it does default to **ON**, although I'm not confident this is really the case yet.

What technical details we do have come from this bit:

> Custom Visualforce pages with the showHeader attribute in the apex:page element set to true within a frame or iframe.

This implies there will be a somewhat standard frame buster script inserted on every visualforce page with showHeader="true" and all standard SFDC pages.

Outside of a leak directly from R&D I think this is the extent of the available information.

Comment: I'd love to hear confirmation on the default - it has the potential to break a lot of existing code if it's on by default.

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that VF pages that use the `standard controller` are the only ones that will be affected by the new click jacking setting.